# Find length of Array within JSON column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to give a score on my query results. Each `'categories'` array might contain many category integers, or it might be `null`. If it's null then it should be considered as found.

In the query below I'm searching for category `3` which is found. However **I don't know how I can check if the Array categories is** `NULL` so I can return 1 as well which will solve my problem.

I have tried:

```
WHERE Value IN(3) OR Value IS NULL)

WHERE Value IN(3) OR Value.length =0)

WHERE Value IN(3) OR Value = '')
```

etc....

For example

1. `{"categories":[1,2,3],"distance":[130,300],"companysize":[2,4],"budget":[5000,1000000]}`
2. `{"categories":[],"distance":[60,200],"companysize":[1,2],"budget":[250,100]}`

SQL

```
     SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
             (CASE WHEN EXISTS (Select * FROM OPENJSON(Preference,'$.categories') 
              WHERE Value IN(3) OR Value IS NULL)  -- < problem is here
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              matchscore, p.*
              FROM FinNotificationsPreferences p) x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your code:

```
Select * FROM OPENJSON(Preference,'$.categories') WHERE Value IN(3) OR Value IS NULL
```

with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (Preference) WHERE [key] = 'categories' AND ([value] like '%3%' OR [value] = '[]')
```

The problem with your use of OPENJSON(Preference, '$.categories) is that when the array is empty, the OPENJSON table function returns no rows. This is indistinguishable from the case when the categories array has values, but none of them are '3'.  So, we need to change our methodology.

By simply checking OPENJSON(Preference) and parsing the value for categories for a 3 or '[]' we either get 1 or 0 rows back.  1 row means our condition is found, 0 means its a miss.

NOTE: this parsing has some big shortcomings.  If there's a category like 13, 23, 30, 300, etc... all these will match our %3% pattern.  I leave it to you to harden the parsing as needed.  I don't know your use cases.

Comment: I didn't like the like '%3%' part but your answer guided me to the solution. You can adjust your answer based on this:  SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
             (
    (CASE WHEN 
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (Preference) WHERE [key] = 'categories' AND (EXISTS (Select * FROM OPENJSON([value]) WHERE Value IN (3)) OR [value] = '[]'
    )         
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    )
              matchscore, p.*
              FROM FinNotificationsPreferences p) x